# NumPy Under Xen Client System

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, virtualization, xen

I am working on a project built on NumPy, and I would like to take advantage of some of NumPy's optional architecture-specific optimizations.  If I install NumPy on a paravirtualized Xen client OS (Ubuntu, in this case - a Linode), can I take advantage of those optimizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The optimizations run in userland and so shouldn't cause any PV traps.